# UTF в Python WSGI

Tags: python, uwsgi

Собственно код:

```
def app(environ, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-type', 'text/html')])
    with codecs.open("template.html", 'r', 'utf8') as template_file:
        template_content = template_file.read()
    return template_content
```

И пустой ответ сервера

```
GET / => generated 0 bytes in 1 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 1 headers in 44 bytes (1105 switches on core 0)
```

Документ пустой.
Если template_content заменить на u"Привет" - то же самое. "Привет" - ответ нормальный.

return str(template_content) выдает ошибку кодировки

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 82-86: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Проверял на uwsgi и wsgiref.simple_server

Comment: Статические файлы лучше оставить http-серверам таким как nginx. Если всё таки хотите сами посылать, то можно файл без перекодирования послать (откройте в 'rb' режиме и кусками yield). Не ясно, зачем руками wsgi приложение создавать. Попробуйте микро-framework типа [bottle](http://bottlepy.org)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
return [template_content.encode('utf-8')]
```

Comment: Да, конечно. Упустил, что unicode строки не совсем "байтовые" и нужно преобразовать. Что еще печальнее, сутки плясал с бубном вокруг этой мысли и так и не проверил. Спасибо. Если придраться, то точнее return [template_content.encode('utf-8')], т.к. WSGI должен возвращать итерируемый объект, элементами которого являются байты.

Comment: @KamoPetrosyan если придираться, то в Python 2 байтовые строки это итерируемые объекты, элементами которого являются байтовые строки :)

Comment: @andreymal [`application = wsgiref.validate.validator(app)` подскажет](http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2015/05/returning-string-as-iterable-from-wsgi.html?m=1) что не следует строку напрямую возвращать. Следует обернуть (в список).

Comment: @jfs KamoPetrosyan ваша правда, исправил.